# How to hide default keyboard from ListViewAdapter in android

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, hide, android-softkeyboard

I am using ListViewAdapter for binding ListView on my home page, and a custom keyboard. But when I clicked on EditText, the default keyboard displays.

I tried to hide it by using the following code:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(diesel.getWindowToken(), 0);

activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

But it didn't work.

How can I hide the default keyboard from ListViewAdapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i got it. i solved this problem.
just added below line in ListViewAdapter.

(EditTextName).setInputType(0);

Now it will not open Default Keyboard on EditText Click or Touch.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to hide the keyboard on events like click of button, use this

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
     InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: this is best solution because it has no side effect

Answer (score 4):

Adapter is not the right place to do **any** UI related activities.